# Root causes of a memory leak in Commit Size

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks

I am trying to understand why my c# application is leaking memory (over the span of several weeks) by indefinitely increasing the Commit Size. All the Disposable objects are being disposed or embedded in using() blocks. So my question is, **what kind of leak would cause an increase in the Commit Size but not in the Working Set?**

The application runs as a Windows Service and makes use of remoting by marshalling through AppDomains. The main tasks include data manipulation and communication with a database (Oracle, through ODP.NET).

I am using a lot of AppDomain instantiation/unloading, but apparently everything is going fine there as well (I am checking that the AppDomains are correctly unloaded afterwards).

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should provide more details. Web app or Windows Forms? Using Remoting or not? etc.

Comment: Sounds like you are leaking types over app domain boundaries.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question with more details. In order to check whether I'm leaking types over appdomains, would it be enough to check the number of loaded assemblies in the main AppDomain?

Comment: Have you tried using tools to find the leak? MemProfiler is great, but free tools like CLR Profiler or WinDbg with SOS should also work.

Comment: Yes, and up to now the results were inconclusive.. What about the question in bold (which kind of leak can affect the Commit Size but not the Working Set)?

Comment: I have this same problem. More interesting is that my code is c++ and is compiled for Windows and for Linux and both seem to have some sort of leak problem. But the private working set and other memory counts are all low in the tens of MB while the Commit Size is 37GB right now. And I can sit and watch it go up in real-time because my program is memory intensive, to say the least.